# How to do line animations that transform into 3d models?

Tags: animation, wireframe

Dear Blender community,

I'm a 3D artist specialising in 3D modeling and Architecture. For my upcoming architectural 3D films I need artistic constructional animations but I have no idea where to start.

I'm desperately searching for a software that can create this type of animations

• https://vimeo.com/109276484

• https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrAujOIJJHE&list=WL

• https://vimeo.com/110243429

Somebody told me that the videos from Vimeo were made with Blender. Can experts confirm this? If it's true, could you pinpoint to some tutorials for beginners?

I have 9 years of professional experience with SketchUp but SketchUp doesn't do animations. I've known about Blender since ages but I was staying away from it because of the unwelcoming and uncomfortable UI and steep learning curve. But there's version 2.8 now and I'm excited to add Blender to my arsenal of programs. I just don't know if it's the right program for this kind of stuff.

Please help, I feel so overwhelmed by this task. I'd be very grateful for any advice or guidance.
Cheers,
Vahe

Comment: The first piece of advise is to drop the "overwhelmed" part... Learning takes time and effort, it's up to you to do it. The software is not the one doing things, you are. Then Look for videos ("tutorials") on grease pencil and freestyle rendering in blender.

Comment: The thing you want wo have a look at: Curves and curve animations in Blender, Grease Pencil and maybe Animation Nodes. This will take a lot of time to create a Setup and wrap your head around it, but you can then probably use that template for different Visualisations. Aditionally the animations you are linking are not as similar as they might look like at first glance and represent different levels of difficulty.